# Problem with focal minimum when using with diagonal weights matrix

Tags: r, statistics, raster, minimum

I am trying to calculate the minimum value of the cells using a moving window with diagonal matrix weight in `raster::focal`. However, I am not getting the expected results. Please see the example below

```
r <- raster(resolution=5, xmn=0, xmx=200, ymn=0, ymx=300)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r)
```

[image]

Generating focal raster using a column matrix weight and fun = minimum

```
r_min_c <- focal(r, matrix(1, nrow = 5, ncol = 1), fun = min, na.rm = T)
plot(r_min_c)
```

[image]

Works fine!

Generating focal raster using a diagonal matrix weight and fun = maximum

```
r_max_d <- focal(r, diag(1, nrow =5, ncol = 5), fun = max, na.rm = T)
plot(r_max_d)
```

[image]

Works fine!

But when trying to generate a focal raster using a diagonal matrix weight and fun = minimum it gives a zero matrix

```
r_min_d <- focal(r, diag(1, nrow =5, ncol = 5), fun = min, na.rm = T)
plot(r_min_d)
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how to do this correctly?

Comment: I'm maybe being a bit daft here, but if you apply a weight of zero won't this then produce a minimum of zero which you see. (you see asimilar result with `mask = matrix(1, nrow =5, ncol = 5); mask[1,1] = 0`)

Comment: I am not using a weight of zero everywhere, the diagonal has a weight of one, so my understanding is that it calculates the minimum of the cells located diagonally including the cell of interest.

Comment: Perhaps. But form the details section of `focal` it shows that the mean can be calculated by applying the relevant weighted mask or using a function. This leads me to believe that the weights in the mask multiply the raster values. So with the diagonal matrix, you get raster values multiplied by zero. Hence the min value would be zero.

Comment: You are right. I was doing that bit wrong. `function (x) min (x[x>0], na.rm = T)` solved the issue. If you answer with the above comment I will accept it.

Comment: Pls feel free to write up.